# What is Nioman water?

Tags: meaning, poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire

Jakub Kolas's poem *Evenings* (from *The New Land*) contains the following lines:

> I see level lands, far over
> Nioman water, and their clothing

What is Nioman water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nioman is the Belarusian name for a river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neman) that rises in central Belarus and flows north-west through Lithuania and then along the Lithuania–Kaliningrad border to the Baltic. It is also known as the Nemunas (in Lithuanian), the Niemen (in Polish), the Neman (in Russian) and the Memel (in German).

One of the senses of ‘water’ in English is ‘river’:

> **water, *n.* 11.b.** A body of flowing water; a river or stream.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>